# How do I get a list of the subversion projects stored in a database when all I know is the path of the database?

Tags: svn

We are currently using git and the git repo only goes back to when the subversion repo was imported with no history.  We are being asked to produce earlier version of the source code for a project that predates all of us.  I was able to locate where the original subversion database was located in the file system of an old machine:

```
/store/svn/project/db
```

The question is how do I bring this back online so that I can browse the projects that are in it and more important look at the version of the code in them?

Comment: How do the file structure look under /db/* ? Maybe `svnadmin dump` helps already. Good luck if FS_TYPE was still BDB...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Smacking my forehead for asking this.  All I had to do was simply install the subversion server on the machine and start it:

```
svnserve -d
```

then I was able to get a list of the repos in it:

```
svn list --verbose file:///store/svn/project

   3659 john               21 Oct 29  2008 .gitignore
   7946 charlie               May 26  2009 branches/
   7945 ip                    May 22  2009 tags/
   7953 miles                 Jul 02  2009 trunk/
```